# How does C++ linker handle references to static strings?

Tags: c++, windows, x86, portable-executable

I'm trying to better understand the structure of the Windows PE executable files and namely how does C++ linker handle static variable references. (In my case for Visual Studio C++.)

Say I have the following example:

```
::PathFindExtension(L"file.exe");
```

which may translate into the following assembly (Debug build in this case):

[image]

I understand that the pointer to the `PathFindExtension` API for the `call` instruction is calculated and inserted into the PE image at the .exe file start-up when the corresponding DLL is loaded in, but I'm not clear about how pointers to static strings are handled.

As you see the `push` instruction:

```
00568AC6 68 70 48 60 00   push        offset string L"file.exe" (604870h)
```

is `68 id` machine code, or `PUSH imm32` [[source](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html)], thus the `imm32` is just an absolute reference to memory, or `604870h` in this case:

[image]

But my question is, since that value is hardcoded at the compile time, how was that offset (i.e. `604870h`) calculated?

And the second question, how does [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) handle this situation, i.e. when this executable could be loaded at some arbitrary address in memory? (If I understand ASLR concept correctly.)

Comment: It's most likely an offset from the beginning of the code segment, where string literals are usually stored.

Comment: Look into assembly output rather than executable

Comment: this value (`604870`) not hardcoded in compile time but finally calculated at link time. and if pe have relocation's -  one of relocs if point to `568ac7` - so PE can be relocated. if no relocation's (this depend from linker command line) - ASLR nothing do with this exe

Comment: The address is calculated by the linker, under the assumption that the binary gets loaded at its preferred base address. The linker also generates relocation tables that are used by the loader to fix up the code. The new address is calculated as: `current value - preferred base + actual base`.

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant to say `linker`. Thanks for the info, guys.

Comment: In 64-bit position-independent code, you'd use a RIP-relative `lea` to get an address into a register and push that, so your code doesn't require modification at load time.  It would only contain relative references to static data, not absolute.  32-bit code doesn't have PC-relative addressing, though.

Comment: Applications operate in terms of virtual memory addresses, which then translated to physical addresses. Every process created to run this example will have virtual address 604870h pointing to the string L"file.exe". Physical addresses may vary.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I don't think 64-bit code uses position-independent reference in this case. It compiles to `lea rcx,[7FF751F40448h]` which is technically the same thing. In x64 the first parameter in a function call is passed via `rcx` register and not pushed on to the stack like in x86. And thus they load the address into `rcx`, which is basically the same thing.

Comment: @hutorny: No, also incorrect. That is not how `ASLR` works. True, there's virtual-to-physical page translation, but that's a different subject. `ASLR` should randomize base addresses where executable modules load in virtual memory. (But maybe it does so with DLLs only.)

Comment: That has to be a RIP-relative addressing mode.  An absolute effective address can still only use a disp32, and `0x7FF751F40448` doesn't fit in a signed-extended 32-bit displacement.  The only way to put a 64-bit immediate into a register is with the special `mov r64, imm64` encoding.  No other instructions take a 64-bit immediate.  If you look in the machine code, the last 4 bytes of the LEA will be `0x7FF751F40448 - address of the end of that instruction` (in little-endian signed 2's complement)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes. That's how they load `0x7FF751F40448` address of the `L"file.exe"` string into `rcx`.

Comment: Right, so it *is* position-independent code, which doesn't need runtime fixups.  (And yes, you're right about the calling-convention difference meaning no `push` is needed, I should have noticed that this was a function arg.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: OK. Yes. My bad. I didn't check the machine opcodes for that instruction. So on x64 it is indeed a relative address, i.e. `00007FF7CBC904AD  48 8D 0D 94 FF 03 00  lea rcx,[7FF7CBCD0448h]` that is calculated as `7FF7CBC904B4h + 03FF94h = 7FF7CBCD0448h`, where first number is the `RIP`, or address following the instruction. For x86 though, it's all hardcoded, i.e. `003C5A75  68 E8 E1 3E 00   push offset string L"file.exe" (3EE1E8h)`. So I'm again puzzled how ASLR can be used with such approach on x86 processes.

Comment: IDK how it's done on Windows.  Linux doesn't try to ASLR position-dependent code, but Windows still cares about x86-32.  I'd guess that it actually modifies the machine code at load time.  (Probably using a symbol table that lists all the absolute addresses that need fixups if it doesn't load at its preferred virtual address.)  So anyway, apparently it's not the linker, but rather the loader that's doing it.  I think earlier comments already said this.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's correct. If a module cannot be loaded at its preferred base address, it gets relocated, and the machine code is patched at load time. Larry Osterman has more details: [Why should I even bother to use DLL’s in my system?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/07/06/why-should-i-even-bother-to-use-dlls-in-my-system/).

Comment: @IInspectable: And it does ASLR by intentionally not loading at the preferred address, even if it's available?

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, if relocation exist for *PE* and ASLR enabled for it - windows calculated some random base for it and try load this *PE* at this base, even if it preferred base is free. also this base common for all processes - windows try in all processes load image at this new base